# How can I apply all Modifiers at once?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have a scene that has hundreds of modifiers in it. When I try to render my scene, it takes **FOREVER**, so long that I cannot even render the scene! Help me please! How can I apply all of these modifiers all at once? I don't want to have to manually click "Apply" hundreds of times!